# How do I populate Struct/Array of Records using Delphi?

Tags: arrays, delphi, record

I want to populate an array of records, and with my recent exposure to TMappedFile, I am trying to duplicate it, w/o actually using unFileMapping or BlockRead/Write. The purpose is to leave my options open just for that. The problem I am finding is either its not initiating or Create'ing my array correctly.

From what I have seen so far, is that the `DataArr` remains `nil` after compiling. And causes an memory violation error (0x00000000) which means it's empty/null. My engineer has already addressed to me that the size of the array maybe to large for purpose, and has also mentioned that I am not able to do what I want unless I deference the pointer, ex. `DataArr^[0].value1`

I believe my confusion lies with SetLength which seems counter intuitive for a Dynamic Array, which is why I commented it out. Otherwise I get an error `E2008 incompatible types`.

```
type
  TDataStruct = Record
  value1 : array[0..1] of Single;
  value2 : array[0..1] of Single;
  value3 : array[0..1] of Single;
  end;

  TDataStructArray = array[0..MaxInt div SizeOf(TDataStruct) - 1] of TDataStruct;
  PDataStructArray = ^TDataStructArray;

var
  DataArr: PDataStructArray;

begin
  //SetLength(DataArr,length(DataArr)+1);
  DataArr[0].value1[0] := 2;
```

Other things that I have tried is used `FillChar(DataArr,SizeOf(DataArr),0)` and as well as `FillChar(DataArr[0], SizeOf(DataArr[0]) * Length(DataArr));`

The following links have been my sources

1. [How to delete an Index of the Dynamic Array of Records](http://www.delphipages.com/forum/showthread.php?t=108538)
2. [Using New/Dispose with record pointer containing WideString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37743076/using-new-dispose-with-record-pointer-containing-widestring)
3. [Assigning a pointer of a record to an array of char in Delphi - come again?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4657073/assigning-a-pointer-of-a-record-to-an-array-of-char-in-delphi-come-again)
4. [How do i declare an array when i don't know the length until run time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433221/how-do-i-declare-an-array-when-i-dont-know-the-length-until-run-time)

Comment: Why aren't you using dynamic arrays?

Comment: The problem is that the pointer is not pointing to anywhere. To populate an array of records, first you have to have an array of records, you have none.

Comment: As others have suggested, you should use a dynamic array. If you want to use a pointer to an array as you have then you need to get memory for that array before you use it and free the memory afterwards. e.g. for 5 records in the array you would do: `GetMem(DataArr, SizeOf(TDataStruct) * 5);` `DataArr[0].value1[0] := 2;` `FreeMem(DataArr);`

Comment: You don't have any array so far, only the helper types.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A [dynamic array](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Structured_Types#Dynamic_Arrays) is what is says: dynamic.

> Dynamic arrays do not have a fixed size or length. Instead, memory for a dynamic array is reallocated when you assign a value to the array or pass it to the SetLength procedure.

Declare

```
DataArr: Array of TDataStruct;
```

Use [SetLength](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SetLength) to allocate records and initialize them at the same time.

```
SetLength(DataArr,Length(DataArr)+1); // Or preallocate as many as you wish to initialize
```

Access a record in the array:

```
DataArr[0].value1[0] := 2;
```

---

In your example there is no memory allocation made, hence the error. And `SetLength` operates on dynamic arrays, not on pointers to static arrays.

You could manage the pointer with GetMem/FreeMem and initialize with ZeroMem, but that will only cause troubles building and maintaining the code.

Comment: Another option is to use a variable, to allocate memory for the static array I mean..

Comment: @SertacAkyuz, from the look of the question, it seems that the size of the array is not known at compile time.

Comment: I need to make a loop verification with this method, and everytime I do that, I receive a code violation. But if I add the [0..0] I get the error 'incompatible types' when I try to increase the array size. Do you know what can I be doing wrong?

Comment: @riki481, hard to say why the dynamic array allocation fails without seeing your code. A static array is incompatible with a dynamic array and cannot be resized, hence the compiler error.